# Is nudity as common at the Australian Burning Man as at the original US Burning Man?

Tags: usa, australia, nudism, events, burning-man

It's pretty well known that the original Burning Man event held annually in is about as free and "do your thing" as possible, to the point that numerous people are always wandering around naked.

But I just learned that Australia also has its own regional Burning Man event. Is this kind of nudity common there too or are the Aussies not quite that free?

Comment: This question works both ways: **a)** Naked people are horrifying so warn me if they're there so I know not to go. **b)** Naked people are awesome so let me know if I should go join them. Feel free to answer the question from either perspective.

Comment: It's considered good manners to leave a constructive comment about why you've voted down or voted to close a question. I see there are three such votes all too shy to leave a comment? (-;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is nudity. Burning Man US is all about lots of booze, dope & free love. Here are some photos of Burning Seed

http://www.offmyfacebook.com.au/burning-seed-australia.html

Comment: your link is dead. Please update.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, to get an overall impression of what to expect, Youtube as always has a great video, titled "[Burning Seed 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jT4-tZp_sL0)" - of Australia's first Burning Man event.  From arriving, to the partying, fire, and more, it gives a solid 12 minute taste.   The only problem is in answering your question with the video - much of the footage is at night, and it's not always easy to tell whether people are clothed as they're often just silhouettes!

Then there's the trailer for [2011's Burning Man](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fporEjDRTm8) in Australia.  This runs for about 3 minutes, and including the climactic final scene around the fire, there is no sign of nudity - despite being a trailer, I'd have thought it hard to hide AND include that final scene.

However, one of the founding and guiding principles of the event is radical self-expression, so it certainly seems from that, that nudity would be tolerated or even embraced.  Probably find it just takes one, and others will follow...

The [website for the Australia Burning Man](http://www.burningmanaustralia.com/) event.

Comment: One problem is that YouTube does not allow nudity. Another problem is that the Event almost certainly doesn't want to promote itself as something they're trying to attract gawkers, since that would work against the environment they're trying to create. I'm guessing the answers lie with people that have been there or are discussing past and future events on forums.